# LayoutParams haven't been applied when requesting their width and height

Tags: java, android

We're working on an android application, but we got stuck on a problem.
We are using rectangles to calculate the hitbox of (in this case) dots. But we also want to set the size of these dots in accordance with the size of the screen.
So this could be done when creating the dots, but, because we place the dots in a (horizontally oriented) LinearLayout that is created programmatically, the size of these LinearLayouts cannot be obtained before they have actually been drawn. So we did find a solution for that on here, namely by setting the LayoutParams in an overwritten method onWindowFocusChanged. This works, the size is set. But, right after that we want to calculate the sizes of the rectangles, and again, our dots have not been drawn yet, so again, the sizes of the rectangles aren't correct. Is there a way to solve this?
Our onWindowFocusChanged() currently is this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus){
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus){
        //setting scaled layout for dots and lines and boxes
        setParameters();

        //making hitbox rectangles for dots
        makeHitboxRectangles();
    }
}
```

Our setParameters() method:

```
private void setParameters () {
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    double llWidth = (double) ll.getWidth();
    double margin = (0.03*llWidth);
    double widthRatio1 = llWidth - (2 * margin);
    double widthRatio2 = 3.*wp.getMatrix().getN()+1.;
    double widthRatio = widthRatio1 / widthRatio2;
    int dotSize = (int) widthRatio;
    int lineWidth = 2 * dotSize;
    int lineHeight = dotSize;

    Log.i(TAG, "llWidth =" + llWidth + ", margin =" + margin + ", Dotsize =" + dotSize + "/" + widthRatio + ", part1 =" + widthRatio1 + ", part2 =" + widthRatio2);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams dotParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dotSize,dotSize);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams hLineParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lineWidth, lineHeight);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams vLineParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lineHeight, lineWidth);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams blockParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lineWidth, lineWidth);

    for (int i=0; i<wp.getMatrix().getM()+1; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<wp.getMatrix().getN()+1; j++) {
            dots[j][i].setLayoutParams(dotParams);
            dots[j][i].setSize(dotSize);
            dots[j][i].invalidate();
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].isHorizontal()) {
            lines[i].setLayoutParams(hLineParams);
            lines[i].invalidate();
            lines[i].setWidth(lineWidth);
            lines[i].setHeight(lineHeight);
        } else {
            lines[i].setLayoutParams(vLineParams);
            lines[i].setWidth(lineHeight);
            lines[i].setHeight(lineWidth);
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<blocks.length; i++) {
        blocks[i].setLayoutParams(blockParams);
        blocks[i].setSize(lineWidth);
        blocks[i].invalidate();
    }
}
```

Our makeHitboxRectangles() method:

```
private void makeHitboxRectangles() {
    for (int i=0; i<wp.getMatrix().getM()+1; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<wp.getMatrix().getN()+1; j++) {
            int[] coords = new int[2];
            ((LinearLayout) dots[j][i].getParent()).getLocationOnScreen(coords);
            Log.i(TAG, "for dot id=" + dots[j][i].getID() + ", layout coords =" + coords[0] + ", " + coords[1]);
            rects[j][i] = new Rect(
                    dots[j][i].getLeft(),
                    dots[j][i].getTop() + coords[1],
                    dots[j][i].getRight(),
                    dots[j][i].getBottom() + coords[1]);
            Log.i(TAG, "rect for id=" + dots[j][i].getID() + " is (" +
                    dots[j][i].getLeft() + ", " +
                    ( dots[j][i].getTop() + coords[1] ) + ", " +
                    dots[j][i].getRight() + ", " +
                    ( dots[j][i].getBottom() + coords[1] ) + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, if more code samples are needed, please say so.

-Bob

EDIT:
https://pastebin.com/Nq8v6Uun

Comment: Question is not clear , Do you want to know the display width  or the layout width?

Comment: @Krish It's not really a question more of a problem we encountered, when we call makeHitBoxRectangles(), the changes from setParameters() haven't been applied

Comment: Whether the Log printing it correct or not?

Comment: @Krish the log prints that the first horizontal linearlayout is the size of the whole screen, and all the others have a size of 0.

Comment: Can you post the logs ?

Comment: @Krish added them

Comment: what is this line says dots[j][i].setSize(dotSize);

Comment: @Krish it sets the size of the DotView so the DotView knows what size it has, it's only used in the DotView class.

Comment: maybe the linearlayout has no child views inside. because of that it showing zero

Comment: And from the logs it seems that , from the dot id 5 (for dot id=5, layout coords =0, 1920)  The layout is offscreen . Did you set orientation for LinearLayout ?

Comment: @Krish yes, the orientation of all the linearLayouts in the array is set to Horizonal. The thing is, everything works perfectly fine when the device is locked and unlocked

Comment: Did you calling requestLayout in parent view after setting new layoutParams?